# I am above the return, enter if you will

Tags: riddle, wordplay, poetry

> If my prefix could mean to revert
>   And my suffix could mean lacerate
>   Then what in the world could I be
>   Given I could ensure your escape?

Hint:

> You could eat me in a single 'bite'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess

> **backslash**

*If my prefix could mean to revert*

> **back**

*And my suffix could mean lacerate*

> **slash**

*Then what in the world could I be

Given I could ensure your escape?*

> A **backslash** is used as an *escape* sequence in programming

Hint:

> As wordplay is implied, *bite* could refer to *byte* where an escape sequence usually occupies one byte in memory.

As for the title

> The most common keyboard layouts would have the backslash key above the return key.

Comment: Good job! Could you include the reference to the answer in the title? Looking forward to your next riddle!

Comment: @shanylong Done!

Comment: This must be specific to America because rot13(va gur HX gur onpxfynfu xrl vf ba gur yrsg bs gur xrlobneq, arkg gb gur "M"!)

Comment: @lioness99a I used the British layout long back as well, that’s why I included the word *’most’*.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac I noted that, my comment was more about the original puzzle wording :) I stared at it for a while trying to make rot13(onpxfcnpr) fit instead!

Comment: @lioness99a Oh alright! I'm from Singapore and our keyboards here follow the US layout... I did not realise there was a difference in the positioning of the backslash key between the two layouts...